# Собрать массив с помощью PHP

Tags: php, json

У меня есть цикл, который заполняет `$jsonData`:

```
foreach($result as &$item)
{
    $jsonData = [$item["name"], $item["surname"]];
    echo json_encode($jsonData);
}
```

Выходит это:

```
["name", "surname"]["name", "surname"]["name", "surname"]
```

А как получить это?:

```
{"items": [["name", "surname"],["name", "surname"],["name", "surname"]]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю отказаться от цикла и сделать нечто подобное:

```
$array['items'] = [
    ['name1', 'surname1'],
    ['name2', 'surname2'],
    ['name3', 'surname3']
];

echo json_encode($array);
// Выведет: {"items":[["name1","surname1"],["name2","surname2"],["name3","surname3"]]}
```

Или так, если name и surname это ключи вложенных массивов:

```
$array = [
    [
        'name' => 'Арсений',
        'surname' => 'Петров'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Игорь',
        'surname' => 'Семёнов'
    ]
];
// Сбросим ключи у вложенных массивов
$array = array_map('array_values', $array);
$jsonData = json_encode(
    ['items' => $array],
    JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
);

echo $jsonData;
// Выведет: {"items":[["Арсений","Петров"],["Игорь","Семёнов"]]}
```

Comment: а как из цикла динамически добавлять элементы? например добавить еще ['name' . $length, 'surname' + $length]

Comment: Что у Вас лежит в переменной $result? Приведите пример.

Comment: там лежит $query->fetchAll(), но я уже разобрался, как добавить элемент из цикла: `array_push($array['items'], ['name4', 'surname4']`

Comment: @cafeed Дополнил вторым примером, мб пригодится

Answer (score 0):

Сделать предопределение ключа items, это то, куда ты будешь писать.

Например в цикле foreach исправь на это:

```
$jsonData['items'] = ....
```